# Binding Generic List in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

**C#**

```
List<Rating> ratingList = new List<Rating>();

public class Rating
{
    public string CustomerName;
}

RptCustomerRating.DataSource = ratingList;
RptCustomerRating.DataBind();
```

In the debugmode the List is filled. But in the itemtemplate Eval doesn't work at all...

**Aspx File Version 1**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptCustomerRating" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
             <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                      <h2><%#Eval("CustomerName") %></h2>
                  </div>
             </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

My Error: 
System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: CRating+Rating contains no property named CustomerName.

**Aspx File Version 2**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptCustomerRating" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Repeater ID="inner" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h2><%#Eval("CustomerName") %></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

This is what i found on stackoverflow. Someone recommend to solve the problem with nested repeaters. Well Visual Studio can't find a error, but in this case nothing happend. The html part is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `get` and `set` the property `CustomerName`

```
public class Rating
{
    public string CustomerName {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Field, not Property. That's why you got such error.

```
public class Rating
{
    public string CustomerName; // <= this is a field
}

public class Rating
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set;} // <= this is a property
}
```

[Difference between fields and properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c)